# Detect Touch on Surfaceview android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I'm creating a camera app and need to detect Touch on `surfaceView` which is camera preview. I want to set focus of camera where user touch. But Right i just only need to detect touch place.

Here is my preview class code.

```
public class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    public Preview(Context ctx, SurfaceView surfaceView) {
      super(ctx);
      init(surfaceView);
    }

  private void init(SurfaceView surfaceView){
        mSurfaceView = surfaceView;
        final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
  }
  public void setCamera(){
     mCamera = Camera.open()
         mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceView.getHolder());
            mCamera.startPreview();
  }
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onInterceptTouchEvent");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onTouchEvent");
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
 // Other code.... like override methods etc
```

**MainActivity**

```
  // inside onCreate() method
  preview = new Preview(this, surfaceView);
    RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    mainLayout.addView(preview);
  preview.setCamera();
  // Other codes .....
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/mainLayout">
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I added `onTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` But both are not working. Whenever I touched on `sufaceView` nothing show in **Log** I think I'm missing some thing, can you please let me know ?

Comment: Can you show how are you using `Preview`? How are you adding it to your view hierarchy?

Comment: I'm using `Preview` in `onCreate` method.  Everything is working fine there is no error. Just I want to detect touch on surfaceView @azizbekian

Comment: @azizbekian There is just two line code in `MainActivity` initilizing the `Preview` and `setCamera()` nothing else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> preview = new Preview(this, surfaceView);
>
> preview.setCamera();
>
> There is just two line code in MainActivity initilizing the Preview and setCamera() nothing else.

**Why you do not see `onTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` logs?**

I assume, that you haven't added that layout to your view hierarchy.

```
 rootView.addView(preview);
```

After adding it you should see touch event logs.

But that's not what you actually expect to do, because you have just incorrectly "wrapped" your `SurfaceView` inside a Java class, which yet doesn't mean that touch events on your `SurfaceView` would be reflected in your logs.

What you really want is to `extend SurfaceView` and override those touch events there. Now you would receive correct touch events. Then make sure you are inflating your custom `SurfaceView` into view hierarchy.

Or, second approach, you can add `SurfaceView` as a child of your `ViewGroup`:

```
yourCustomViewGroup.addView(surfaceView);
```

Comment: I extend the `Preview` class from `SurfaceView` but still not getting any **Logs**  And now there is no `onInterceptTouchEvent` method

Comment: How do you inflate `Preview`? Through `xml`? Show your `xml`.

Comment: Check the update in question. There is no `Preview` in `xml`

Comment: Instead of `<SurfaceView>` place `<com.your.package.Preview>`.

Comment: But I think adding `Preview` through java also need to work. You see that I'm adding view in main Layout as you said `mainLayout.addView(preview)`

Comment: Now you have `SurfaceView` (`Preview` is a subclass of `SurfaceView`) which does something with another `SurfaceView`. You should have only one surface view. As said, specify your custom `Preview` in `xml` instead of framework's `SurfaceView`.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks now it's working WHen I changed `surfaceView` with the custom one

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your extended class, in that it does not include all required override methods. However I will assume this is still being developed.

In theory this should work:

```
preview.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

I have not tested it, but as this is extending ViewGroup, this should work.

Note: You probably will need to add this

```
android:clickable="true"
```

To your 'Preview' layout, to allow the click to be processed.

Hope that helps.